# I can't figure out where to start with GIS application development, or which technology to select

Tags: web, gis, geoserver, mapserver

I am very new to GIS development, and to be be frank I have no background about it at all. I searched the web but the tutorials I found seemed to assume the reader has some background information.

the thing is that I am confused about what to read or learn, there seems to be lots of technologies, and I feel lost since some speak about openlayers, geoserver, mapserver,  google maps, and open street maps.

So here is what I am supposed to develop, and I hove you could give me an advice about which technology to use, and where should I start reading - given that I know almost nothing -.

Case 1: a closed system for about 20 users only, who can specify locations on the map, and the web application will store the latitude and longitude of the locations and show the markers. I wanted to use google maps api, but I cancelled that since there license requires you to purchase the service if the system is a closed one. so what technology should I use in such case? I need a free option,  also I will be only using  web server, so if the solution includes using my own geoserver, or something like that I won't be able to do it.

Case 2: I am supposed to display the roads and routes between two given points, and probably add some notes on the map. For this I case I can use my own map server/geo server, but again I want your suggestions.

of course the solution need to be open source

finally, I hope you could tell me what to start reading first,

Comment: Might be more appropriate for http://gis.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by looking over at https://gis.stackexchange.com/, starting with the tags [web-mapping] and

Some topics in particluar you may want to look at are:

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/steps-to-start-web-mapping
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8238/where-how-to-learn-about-getting-started-with-web-gis
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13868/looking-for-a-developer-friendly-web-gis

As for skills and tuorials, look at:

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17227/free-gis-workshops-tutorials-and-applied-learning-material
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/913/web-gis-development-skill-sets

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. I'll check these.